# Directive not compiled with nested DOM

Tags: angularjs

I have the following directive

```
angular.module('frame',[])

.directive('frame',function(){
  return{
    restrict:'E',
    link: function(scope,element){
      console.log(element);
    }
  };
})

;
```

And an excerpt of its unit test

```
it('frame images, centralizing it',function(){

    var elm = $compile("<frame><div>Hi</div></frame>")(scope);
    scope.$digest();

  });
}
```

The `console.log` in the directive doesn't output nothing.

It just works when I have `$compile("<frame></frame>")(scope)`. In other words, when there isn't nothing nested in `<frame></frame>`.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: I'd probably choose a different element than [`<frame>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/frame). Might be an issue with the regular `<frame>` element not supporting content.

Comment: True. Changed the directive's name, all works.